# Todas las posibles combinaciones de movimiento de rama, HEAD, index y árbol de trabajo

Tags: git

Cuales son las operaciones que se deben realizar en git para poder tener todas las combinaciones de movimiento de:

- rama (apuntador)
- HEAD
- index
- árbol de trabajo

?

Asumiendo que tenemos esta historia:

```
* 1234567 (HEAD -> K, b) 2nd
* 7654321 (a) 1st
```

Las ramas `a` y `b` están puestas para facilitar crear los ejemplos.

Answer (score 0):

## Un solo elemento

### rama

```
git checkout --detach; git branch -f K a
```

### HEAD

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --worktree --staged --source=b .
```

O, la forma antigua (todavía funciona):

```
git checkout --detach a; git checkout b -- .
```

### index

```
git restore --staged --source=a .
```

### árbol de trabajo

```
git restore --worktree --source=a .
```

## Combinaciones of 2 elementos

### rama y HEAD

```
git reset --soft a
```

### Rama e (index o árbol de trabajo):

Correr los movientos de los 2 elementos por separado.

### HEAD e index

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --worktree --source=b .
```

### HEAD y árbol de trabajo

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --staged --source=b .
```

### index y árbol de trabajo

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=a .
```

La forma antigua:

```
git checkout a -- .
```

## Combinación de 3 elementos

### todos *excepto* la rama

```
git checkout --detach b
```

### todos excepto HEAD

```
git checkout --detach; git branch -f K a; git restore --staged --worktree --source=a .
```

### todos excepto index

```
git reset --hard a; git restore --staged --source=b .
```

### todos excepto el árbol de trabajo

```
git reset a
```

## Mover todo

```
git reset --hard a
```